# "'function' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

Code:

```
def user(repo, language, page):
  # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
  dictionary = {'language_search': language, 'page': page, 'followers': repo['followers'], 'github_repo': repo['name'],'forked?': repo['fork'], 'forks': repo['forks'], 'github_owner': repo['owner'], 'language': repo['language'], 'created_at': repo['created_at'], 'forks': repo['forks'], 'watchers': repo['watchers'], 'username': user['login'], 'type': user['type'], 'public_repos': user['public_repos'], 'followers': user['followers']}
  fields_user = ['blog', 'company', 'location', 'name']
  fields_repo = ['description']
  if user.get('email'):
    dictionary_2 = {'email': user['email']}
    for key in fields_user:
      if user.has_key(key):
        dictionary[key] = user[key]
    for key in fields_repo:
    if repo.has_key(key):
      dictionary[key] = repo[key]
    shelf[dictionary_2['email']] = dictionary
    shelf.sync()
    return dictionary_2['email']
    print dictionary_2['email']
```

For some reason I keep getting this error:

```
<ipython-input-40-98ec5463ecbd> in user(repo, language, page)
  1 def user(repo, language, page): #returns email address to pass into rapportive
  2   # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
----> 3   dictionary = {'language_search': language, 'page': page, 'followers': repo['followers'], 'github_repo': repo['name'],'forked?': repo['fork'], 'forks': repo['forks'], 'github_owner': repo['owner'], 'language': repo['language'], 'created_at': repo['created_at'], 'forks': repo['forks'], 'followers': user['followers']}
  4   # dictionary = {, , 'watchers': repo['watchers'], 'username': user['login']} , 'type': user['type'], , 'public_repos': user['public_repos']
  5   fields_user = ['blog', 'company', 'location', 'name']

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

And I don't understand why. I just want to write more key:value pairs to dictionary. But for some reason, this keeps throwing off this error.

Comment: Pro tip: Use `key in mapping` instead of `mapping.has_key(key)`. Don't use `mapping.get(key)` for tests where `key in mapping` would do either.

Comment: Counter down vote, this is a common error and people should find it when they search for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user` is a function:

```
def user(repo, language, page):
```

but within that function you are trying to use it as a dictionary instead:

```
 user['followers']
```

on the line where you define `dictionary`:

```
dictionary = {'language_search': language, 'page': page, 'followers': repo['followers'], 'github_repo': repo['name'],'forked?': repo['fork'], 'forks': repo['forks'], 'github_owner': repo['owner'], 'language': repo['language'], 'created_at': repo['created_at'], 'forks': repo['forks'], 'followers': user['followers']}
```

You can split that line up over several to make it more readable and debuggable:

```
dictionary = {
    'language_search': language, 
    'page': page,
    'followers': repo['followers'],
    'github_repo': repo['name'],
    'forked?': repo['fork'],
    'forks': repo['forks'],
    'github_owner': repo['owner'],
    'language': repo['language'],
    'created_at': repo['created_at'],
    'forks': repo['forks'],
    'followers': user['followers']  # `user` is a function, what did you mean instead?
}
```

You seem to expect there to be a `user` dictionary in your function throughout:

```
  if user.get('email'):    # Will also throw the error
    dictionary_2 = {'email': user['email']}  # as will this
    for key in fields_user:
      if user.has_key(key):                  # and this
        dictionary[key] = user[key]          # and here
```

Perhaps you have a global named `user` that is a dictionary? You cannot have both a dictionary *and* a function with the same name in your module. Rename one or the other.